# My deep menu is not working properly

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I want my deep menu to be on the right of the drop down menu. Only with position:relative it shows something, that being a blank space under the hovered link. Changing that to position:absolute nothing appears. I tried also moving the menu all the way to the left , but that didn't work either.

Here's my [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/t9u0u8ax/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="navbar">
        <li class="dropdown"><hr id="tab1"/><a href="#">Models</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-content">
                <li><a href="#">911<i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-fw" style="float:right;margin-top:2px;" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-content2">
                        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Panamera<i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-fw" style="float:right;margin-top:2px;" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cayenne<i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-fw" style="float:right;margin-top:2px;" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><hr id="tab2"/><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><hr id="tab3"/><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><hr id="tab4"/><a href="#">Generations</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .navbar {
        text-align:center;
        margin-top: 0px;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: white;
        position: absolute;
        z-index:200;
        box-shadow:1px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    position:relative;
    padding:0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}
    }
    ul ul{
        visibility: hidden;
        margin-left:10px;
        width:200px;
        box-shadow: 7px 4px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        z-index:-1;
        position:absolute;
        transform: translateY(-3em);
        opacity:0;
        transition: 0.6s;
    }
    ul ul li {
        float:none;
        width:200px;
    }
    ul ul li a{
        text-decoration: none;
        display:block;
        position:relative;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', serif;
        color:black;
        text-align:left;
        font-weight: bold;
        border-top:0.5px solid #d8d8d8;
        transition: 0.6s;
    }
    li:hover:nth-child(1) .dropdown-content{
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0%);
        transition: 0.6s;
    }
    .dropdown-content li a:hover{
        background-color: #9f111d;
        color:white;
        border-color: #9f111d;
        transition:0.6s;
    }
    ul ul ul {
        top:0;
        left:100%;
        float:none;
    }
    .dropdown-content2{
        display: none;
        position:relative;
        color:black;
        box-shadow: 7px 4px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    }
    .dropdown-content li:hover:nth-child(1) > ul{   
        display:block;
    }
```

Comment: "I want my deep menu to be on the left of the drop down menu" what does that mean? This dropdown is on the left edge of the window. If the nested sub-menu is to the left of the dropdown, it will be outside of the window viewport?

Comment: on the right excuse me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This CSS will put the menu to the right. https://jsfiddle.net/t9u0u8ax/2/

```
.dropdown-content li:hover:nth-child(1) > ul {
  /* you already had this rule */
  display:block;

  /* added these styles below */
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  transform: translate(0);
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: wow didn't know i had to put them in the hover element ... tried to add all those things either in the ul or the dropdown-content2 class.Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ValentinDragoi the only thing you really need to include in the hover element is `display: block; opacity: 1; visibility: visible;`. The rest can just be in the menu style wherever, but you have a lot of repetitive CSS so I just put it where I could to keep it simple for me and you. But you may move the top/left/transform/position/margin outside of the hover selector if you want.